# Aspect Before annotation not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspect

Testing out Aspect @Before annotation in a Spring Boot application and it is not working. No Errors thrown. Just simply not working. It is a very simple rest service as below. Been at it for some time now and any tutorials and answers here seems to point that this is correct. My rest service returns correctly. Just that the message from Aspect doesn't print. I am very confident my package structure is correct. Please advice.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class StuffApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StuffApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/information")
public class ContentController {

    @GetMapping("/person")
    public People getPerson(Model model){
        log(); // expecting the aspect print to occur when I call this. 
        // some logic to get personList which works fine
        return new People(personList);
    }

    public void log(){
        System.out.println("This is a logger");
    }

}

@Aspect
@Component
public class JsonAspect {

    @Before(value = "execution(* com.example.stuff.controller.ContentController.log())")
    public void printBefore(){
        System.out.println("I was called before the logger"); // never prints when I call log method
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving`